# MS Access Query date range when last date not found

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have the following update query in MS Access 2013

```
UPDATE WXObs SET WXObs.SnowFlag = 1     
WHERE (((WXObs.StationID) ="451409") And(
(WxObs.ObsDate) Between #1/3/2003# AND #3/29/2003# OR
(WxObs.ObsDate) Between #11/16/2003# AND #5/7/2004# OR
(WxObs.ObsDate) Between #10/30/2004# AND #4/30/2005#));
```

This works until the end date in the range is not found. For instance, if 5/7/2004 is not in the data set, then the update continues to the next end date, in this case 4/30/2005.
I would prefer it ended on the last date in the range. For instance, if the data ended on 4/21/2004, that would be last field updated between 11/16/ and 5/7/2004. The query would then continue to update again beginning on 10/30/2004.

I have tried < and <=

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing some parentheses that are affecting the evaluation order, causing the behavior that you're reporting.

What you want is for each of the `BETWEEN` portions to be evaluated completely before the `OR` option is evaluated, and you need to make sure that evaluation is done by surrounding the `BETWEEN` expressions in parentheses to guarantee the evaluation order.

This should correct it (untested, as you've not provided the test data necessary to create a test case).

```
UPDATE WXObs SET WXObs.SnowFlag = 1     
WHERE 
  (WXObs.StationID ="451409") 
And
  (
   (WxObs.ObsDate Between #1/3/2003# AND #3/29/2003#) OR
   (WxObs.ObsDate Between #11/16/2003# AND #5/7/2004#) OR
   (WxObs.ObsDate Between #10/30/2004# AND #4/30/2005#)
  );
```